# About C++ memory leak

Tags: c++

I want to ask some of the problems about C++ memory leak. And what is my mistake of my programme and how to rewrite the programme to prevent memory leak. Thank you

```
int **ptr = new int*[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  ptr[i] = new int (i+1);
delete ptr;
```

Comment: In a toy example like this, it's easy to count the number of `new` and `new[]` statements and the number of `delete` and `delete[]` statements and see whether they match. You have 1 `new[]` and 5 `new`s. You have 0 `delete[]`s and 1 `delete`. So in this case _none_ of the `new[]` or `new` allocations you created are being cleaned up correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use raw pointers when avoidable. Use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

```cpp
std::vector<int> ptr(5);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  ptr[i] = i+1;
}
```

If you are forced to use raw pointers for some reason, delete whatever you allocated. Also note that you have to use `delete[]` to delete what is allocated via `new[]`.

```cpp
int **ptr = new int*[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  ptr[i] = new int (i+1);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  delete ptr[i];
delete[] ptr;
```

Comment: The first code follows a vector logic, the second one corresponds to a matrix logic ...